# How to Delete or Ignore serializer.data object in serializer.py?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I need to delete serializer.data object in serializer, because i'm having some record in my table. But the entire record details is present in other microservice, Once someone called my api i need to call that service to get the data. But if the record is empty, i need to ignore this object. I can do this view, but it's possible to do in Serializer.py. Check the reference code:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user(self, obj):
        token = self.context['request'].META['HTTP_TOKEN']
        username = get_user_details_from_id(str(obj['user']), token, name=1)
        if username:
            return username
        else:
            obj = {}

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('user', 'total_score')
```

```
[
    {
        "user": "test-User",
        "total_score": 170
    },
    {
        "user": null,
        "total_score": 170
    }
]

               to

[
    {
        "user": "User",
        "total_score": 170
    }
]
```

I want to ignore the record in **SerializerMethodfield** if the username is **empty**

Answer (score -1):

You can override the `.to_representation` method in serializer.

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user(self, obj):
        token = self.context['request'].META['HTTP_TOKEN']
        username = get_user_details_from_id(str(obj['user']), token, name=1)
        if username:
            return username
        else:
            obj = {}

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('user', 'total_score')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(CourseSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        if not data.get('username'):
            data.pop('username', None)
        return data
```

Comment: Not field, entire object. Check the question, i just updated with sample datas.

Comment: @sakthi-panneerselvam did you manage to do it? If so can you show me how?

Comment: @hectorviov, nope. i did it from view now.

Comment: @Mirza715 he wants to delete the entire row, not only the field.